# Stacking elements in 2 responsive columns using only CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

The easiest way to understand what I want to achieve is in the attached image.

Essentially, I want to create a responsive layout comprising of 3 elements within a section - a header, a body, and a footer. On smaller screens (i.e. mobile) the 3 elements simply stack as you'd expect.

However, on larger desktop screens, I want the elements to split into 2 columns - the header and footer on the left, and the body on the right.

The problem is I'm actually not sure I can create this behaviour with CSS alone.

[image: Image to illustrate the problem described above]

The best I can achieve ends up with the footer element staying in line with the bottom of the body element, like the below image (I understand why, I just want to figure out a way around this.)

[image: Image to illustrate the closest solution I have achieved]

I've tried a few methods using floated elements, as well as flexbox solutions and playing with the ordering, but with no success. I even tried some grid stuff, although my knowledge of grid isn't great so I may have missed something.

I know that I could use JS to do something such as moving the header and footer within a single parent element, or back out again, depending upon screen size. But I'm hoping there's a CSS-only way to achieve this, as that doesn't seem very elegant.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: css grid with `grid-template-areas` or flexbox with `flex-order`. What ahve you tried so far? where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `css-grid`with the use of `grid-template-areas"  to define the placement of a specific section as the example below. To allow the body section to extend further then the header and footer, you just need to use 3 rows.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

section {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header {
  grid-area: header;
}

#body {
  grid-area: body;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "header"
        "body"
        "footer";
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    body {
      grid-template-areas:
        "header body"
        "footer body"
        ". body";
      grid-template-columns: 4fr 6fr;
    }
}

/* for styling purpose only */

#body {
  min-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<section id=header>Header</section>
<section id=body>Body</section>
<section id=footer>Footer</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented this solution and it does exactly what I need. I clearly need to learn and use grid more, this is great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used CSS Grid to achieve this, I know you already acheived in Mobile version so I'm just sharing the demo code for Desktop Version. CSS Grid is really powerful you can create complex layout in minutes.

```css
.outer{display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'header body' 'footer body' 'footer body';
    }
.header{width: 100%; grid-area: header; height: 50vh; background-color: yellow;} 
.body{grid-area: body; background-color: red; }
.footer{grid-area: footer; height: 50vh; background-color: violet;}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
<div class='header'> HEADER</div>
<div class='body'> body</div>
<div class='footer'> Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty much the same as the solution I have gone with. I clearly need to learn and use grid more!

Answer (score -1):

I know we are in 2021, but old good simple floats can be used for this task

```css
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  div {
     display: flow-root;
     border: 1px #ccc dashed;
  }   
   
  header, footer { 
     width: 40%; 
     float: left;
  }
  
  main { 
     float: right; 
     width: calc(60% - 10px); 
  }  
   
}

div > * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   color: #fff;
   background: #eb0022;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <header>header</header>
   
   <main>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eos tempore doloremque, illum praesentium atque cumque nulla, dolorum obcaecati quod recusandae itaque pariatur unde soluta blanditiis repudiandae perspiciatis deserunt fuga commodi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eos tempore doloremque, illum praesentium atque cumque nulla, dolorum obcaecati quod recusandae itaque pariatur unde soluta blanditiis repudiandae perspiciatis deserunt fuga commodi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eos tempore doloremque, illum praesentium atque cumque nulla, dolorum obcaecati quod recusandae itaque pariatur unde soluta blanditiis repudiandae perspiciatis deserunt fuga commodi.</p>
      
   </main>
   
   <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: For future readers: I know it's an unpopular opinion because flexbox and grids are _cool_ but you can still use float elements in CSS, if they work. I mean, they were not forbidden and no one will call the police if you use them.

Answer (score -1):

using a div with zero width and height and margin negative of the div the result can be achieved.
[image]

the purple is a div with display flex and a normal  orientation with flex wrap turned on. orange is the footer. it has a  negative margin to equivalent to the body height plus the. the thing in yellow is a div with width and height 0 and margin bottom equivalent to its height of the body. when the page is wide enough both the body and and the yellow div are moved to the side and the negative margin of the footer makes it go up to just bellow the header at the bottom is an in browser version, the yellow square is there to indicate the location of the padding div.

Comment: Thanks, I think this kinda works but seems a bit hacky and requires knowing the exact heights of certain elements. I think some of the other options using grid-template-areas look like the way forwards!

Comment: I downvotes your anwser for following reasons: You anwser is hard to understand, to follow and to reproduce. It is explaiend very vague and difficault. Your approach is complicated as well. To complicated for such an easy task as this. Also you miss a workign code snippet to validate your anwser. A code snippet also clarfies your anwser and shows what you catually do.